# Is there any way to set the alias for command permanently in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, command-line, alias

I'm trying to set the alias for command permanently in `PostgreSQL`.
I've set the alias for a command like given below.

```
Test=> \set x '\\! reset'
```

So, the alias has set for reset the terminal.
While using command, we have to use it like this,

```
Test=> :x
```

So it will clear[reset] the terminal.
But this alias is set for temporarily only. If I logged out from PostgreSQL and again logging in means, This alias is not working.
So I want to know,

> Is there any way to set the alias for command permanently in
>   PostgreSQL?

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Set it up in your "psqlrc"

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to this, So please tell me where I should set this. Because I search the file, But I can't identify

Comment: [psqlrc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN100589) Specify your OS to get the more detailed answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: See the manual for psql; https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html . It covers psqlrc and the file locations.